# initialize pandas dataframe with None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having an hard time to create a DataFrame with None values.
To do so I execute several steps, but I believe that I can get the same results using a pandas' function...

```
mydata = []
mydata.append([None, None, None, None])
mydata = np.array(mydata)
mydata = pd.DataFrame(mydata, columns='Start','End','Duration'])
```

Is there a command to get the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) `numpy array` created from `list`:

```
mydata = pd.DataFrame(np.array([None, None, None]).reshape(-1,3), 
                      columns=['Start','End','Duration'])   
print (mydata)
  Start   End Duration
0  None  None     None
```

Another slowier solution with `[[]]`:

```
mydata = pd.DataFrame([[None, None, None]], columns=['Start','End','Duration'])   
print (mydata)
  Start   End Duration
0  None  None     None
```

If use `columns` and `index` values, all data are `NaN` and is possible [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) them to `None`:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start','End','Duration'], index=[0]))
  Start  End Duration
0   NaN  NaN      NaN

mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start','End','Duration'], index=[0]).replace({np.nan:None})  
print (mydata)
  Start   End Duration
0  None  None     None
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Start':[None],'End':[None],'Duration':[None]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast one-liner:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.empty((4,3),dtype=pd.Timestamp),columns=['Start','End','Duration'])
  Start   End Duration
0  None  None     None
1  None  None     None
2  None  None     None
3  None  None     None
```

In general, an one-liner would go as:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.empty((5,3),dtype=object),columns=['Start','End','Duration'])
  Start   End Duration
0  None  None     None
1  None  None     None
2  None  None     None
3  None  None     None
4  None  None     None
```

Here is a NaN one-liner:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.empty((2,3))*np.nan,columns=['Start','End','Duration'])   
   Start  End  Duration
0    NaN  NaN       NaN
1    NaN  NaN       NaN
```